# How do I update first record in a table using mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an unknown amount of records in the 'room_photos' table. There is a column named 'main_photo' and currently each of the records has a value of 'no' for that column. I would like to create a sql statement that updates the first record in the table and changes the value of the 'main_photo' column to 'yes'.

So this is what I have now:

TABLE **room_photos**
**photo_id**    |    **main_photo**
51               |   no
52               |   no
53               |   no

And this is what I need:

TABLE **room_photos**
**photo_id**    |    **main_photo**
51               |   yes
52               |   no
53               |   no

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use `LIMIT`

```
UPDATE tablename SET main_photo = 'yes' LIMIT 1;
```

The above query will assume that the first record in the table, **regardless of the value of photo_id**, will be updated. If you want the record with the lowest ID to be updated use `ORDER BY`, too:

```
UPDATE tablename SET main_photo = 'yes' ORDER BY photo_id ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori Pretty missing or meaningless comment. Perhaps explain why it's incorrect? It will allow OP to achieve exactly what he wants. ORDER BY could even be DESC to update the last record.